# Post method in django

Tags: python, html, django

I had a tutorial in django with forms and I tried to do exactly what is taught , but I found that either my form in not sending the post method or django can't realize that the request sent is a POST request

here is my file named "register.html":

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form role="form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and here the django side views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages


def register (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
       form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html' , {'form': form})
```

the result is when I click submit , the POST method is not working , I tried to pass a get request and it worked , so the problem only appears when I try to send the POST request , so where is problem ?
In the django's views.py or in the html file ?

Answer (score 0):

Add action url to your form

```
<form role="form" action="/url/" method="post">
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#building-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @c.grey's comment, If the form has errors, then the view will just return the form with form-data pre-filled and error messages associated with the fields and form (your errors might be not visible due to some CSS).

You can also try to see the execution path using a debugger like pdb or ipdb. for example

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages


def register (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
        return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
       print("Request is not == POST")
    return render(request, 'users/register.html' , {'form': form})
```